# error as index was outside the bounds of the array?

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I tried debugging the code...but couldnt rectify...Hope someone gives suggestions

> index was outside the bounds of the array

```
Private Sub loaditems()
    Try
        sqL = "SELECT bills.productname,bills.qty,bills.unitprice,bills.totalamt FROM bills INNER JOIN transactionDetails ON bills.invoiceno = transactionDetails.invoiceID where bills.invoiceno ='" & Trim(lblInvoice.Text) & " '"
        ConnDB()
        cmd = New SqlCommand(sqL, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        dgw.Rows.Clear()

        Do While dr.Read = True
            dgw.Rows.Add(dr(1), dr(0), dr(2), dr(3))
            lblbalance.Text = dr(4)
            dgw.Height += 19
            x += 19
        Loop
        MsgBox("data showing")
        Y = x - 30
        dgw.Height = dgw.Height - 20
        change.Location = New Point(49, 280 + Y)
        lblbalance.Location = New Point(249, 280 + Y)
        lblLine.Location = New Point(52, 299 + Y)
        lblOR.Location = New Point(86, 315 + Y)
        lblThank.Location = New Point(106, 331 + Y)
        btnexit.Location = New Point(198, 369 + Y)
        btnprint.Location = New Point(104, 369 + Y)
        Panel1.Height = Panel1.Height + Y
        Me.Height = Me.Height + Y
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: The line `lblbalance.Text = dr(4)` is the problem. A simple but of debugging would've told you this line is the problem. The exception would've been thrown on this line every time you run the code. The reason for the exception is because the select statement has 4 columns, not 5.

Comment: It worked.... After removing the line of code Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The index starts counting at 0.

this means that:

column 1 has a index of 0

column 2 has a index of 1.

column 3 has a index of 2.

column 4 has a index of 3.

**Column 5 has a index of 4.**  <- dr(4) references column 5.

column 6 has a index of 5

dr(4) references to the fifth column, which does not exist. it only has 4 columns.